# 2-column layout with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make 2-column layout with Twitter Bootstrap. To be simpler, let's say we use Jade:

```
.container
  .row
    .span3
      label Email:
      input(type="text")
      label Password:
      input(type="text")
      input(type="submit")
    .span9
      h1 Hello, world!
      p This is a paragraph.
```

So, my main issue is **input's width is less than span3, and when I specify .span3 for inputs, it breaks grid layout, while resizing**.

And the common question: what is the main rule of classes for elements in BS? Should I wrap all the elements in .spanN's? This code:

```
.row
  .span3
    h1 Hello
```

works the same as simple:

```
.row
  h1.span3 Hello
```

Everything messed up in my head :(

Comment: Try using the "input-block-level" class on your inputs.

Comment: @BillyMoat just what I was looking for, thank you! And what about, for example, buttons (input(type="submit"))? input.btn.input-block-level(type="submit") doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "input-block-level" class on your inputs.

E.G.

```
<input type="text" class="btn input-block-level">
```

To have button elements that are full width you could try setting their width to 100% and make them display block e.g.

```
button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Remember that adding padding and/or border to that button would then make the button's width larger than 100% so in that case you could also set box-sizing on it.

```
button { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```